# How to pass entire elements of a single column of a 2-d array to a function in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

This is how I am passing entire data of single column of tm array in Fortran one by one.

```
MPI_ALLREDUCE(tm(:,1),ptm(:,1),nbins,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
MPI_ALLREDUCE(tm(:,0),ptm(:,0),nbins,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
MPI_ALLREDUCE(tm(:,-1),ptm(:,-1),nbins,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierr)
```

This is how I am trying to pass entire elements of single column of a 2d array in c++. I am not able to pass the entire elements of a particular column.

```
MPI_Allreduce(&MVCLUST->TM->tpm, &MVCLUST->TM->pml, MPI_DOUBLE,MPI::SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD)
```

Comment: This question should also be tagged with fortran and relevant MPI tags.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ 2d arrays are stored row wise so there is no direct way of getting columns out of that which means contiguous memory locations will contain rows and not columns so you can get pointer to row but not for column.

so the approach that you can follow is to first get columns of 2d array in simple 1-d array and then pass that.Sample code for illustration is given below:

```
void printcolumn(int* arr,int len)
{
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main()
{
  int arr[2][2] = {{2,1},{2,2}};
  //2 1
  //2 2
  int col1array[2];
  int cnt =0;
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
      col1array[cnt]=arr[i][0];
      cnt++;
  }
  printcolumn(col1array,2);
  return 0;
}
```